# Add new entity to a list property in Edit method in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have entity which has a list of sub entity .

In Edit Mode i need to Add some Sub Entity to the list. 
but i got this Error in run time :

> Attaching an entity of type 'ResturanCmsAdmin.Models.Image' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

my entity and MY Edit Code is shown as following.

```
public partial class Image
{
    public Image()
    {
        this.News = new HashSet<News>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Edit Code:

```
public ActionResult Edit( Image image)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var item in image.News)
        {
            item.ImageID = image.ID;

            if (item.ID == 0)
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
            else
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

        }
        db.Entry(image).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(image);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is because you are trying to retrieve the entity ˋNews´ from the navigation property. You need a query like ˋvar item = db.Image.Include(n=>n.News)´.

Comment: consider using the **Add** method instead of changing the state. also you can update the image entity without **news** collection and then iterate for each of **news** items.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the Image entity, as the error message indicates. The most probable issue is that the image instance you're trying to track is already tracked by your db instance. Could you provide more information on how the db instance is passed in this method?

Comment: i thank you all  for your good answer. i solve it by view model and  add new sub entities  by code .